# Opening html based on a formular

Tags: html

How to open a web page consisting of values submitted to the selection manu, please?

For instance, Saab, Volvo, and Audi are chosen. After clicking OK, I want to open another HTML page with the chosen words. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>CAR</h1>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type='submit' value='OK'>

// After clicking OK, href consisted of choosen values is open
    <p><a href="https://......./Saab_Volvo_Audi.html" target="_blank">Open</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you wrap your html in a Form element it should work.

And also make sure you add a target parameter to the form element:

```
target="_blank"
```

An example:

```html
<h1>CAR</h1>

<form
  target="_blank"
  action="https://www.lipsum.com"
  method="get"
>
  <label for="car1">Choose a car 1:</label>
  <select id="car1" name="car1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="car2">Choose a car 2:</label>
  <select id="car2" name="car2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="car3">Choose a car 3:</label>
  <select id="car3" name="car3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>
```

**How do you get the values**

To get the values back from the URL, use `window.location.search`.

An example:

```
const searchQuery = window.location.search;
/* '?car1=Volvo&car2=Audi' */

const values = searchQuery.split('?').pop().split('&').map(query => query.split('=').pop());
/* ['Volvo', 'Audi'] */
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And how to get values that were selected and composed the address from them?

Comment: You can use `window.location.search` to get all the query parameters. I added an example to my answer.